# How can I compare SQLAlchemy UTC dates in the user's timezone?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to fetch events to display on a calendar in the user's local time. All dates are stored in Postgres as UTC.

Here's the Event model and the query in question,

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import tz
...

class Event(TimestampMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'events'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    start_date_utc = db.Column(UtcDateTime)
    end_date_utc = db.Column(UtcDateTime)

    user = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('posted_events', lazy='dynamic'))

    ...

    def events_for(self, year, month):
        this_month = datetime(year, month, 1).replace(tzinfo=self.user.tz)
        next_month = this_month + relativedelta(day=1, months=1)
        # TODO: Fix this potential timezone bug -- compare using the user's timezone
        this_month_utc = this_month.astimezone(tz.tzutc())
        next_month_utc = next_month.astimezone(tz.tzutc())
        return self.events \
            .filter(Event.start_date_utc >= this_month_utc) \
            .filter(Event.start_date_utc < next_month_utc) \
            .order_by(Event.start_date_utc, Event.id)

class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    ...

    @property
    def tz(self):
        return tz.gettz('EST')
```

The problem is that this query hits an end-of-the-month edge case. I need query for the events in the context of the user's local time instead. I can't go the other way, converting the user's month boundary to UTC like it's currently written, because of resulting ambiguities leading to more bugs in special cases, e.g. daylight savings boundaries.

How can I change this query to compare in the context of the timezone?

Comment: **How** did you convert the user's month boundary to UTC? What kind of bugs did this lead to? Because that's exactly what I'd do: create a `datetime()` object in the timezone of the user, extend that to cover the month from first day to last, then use that in the query (where it'll be interpreted as UTC automatically, IIRC).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just tweaked the code. Does that help?

Comment: Are you using `pytz` for the timezones?

Comment: I've been testing locally with `tz` for now. Added part of the User model for more context.

Comment: The reason I asked is because the `pytz` timezone info is more extensive than `datetime` anticipated and each timezone comes with historic DST information and offsets, which means that `datetime(year, month, 1).replace(tzinfo=self.user.tz)` could lead to incorrect times and dates; you'd use a method on the timezone object instead to apply the right offsets to the `datetime` object. I am not certain if the `dateutil.tz` database suffers from the same problem.

Comment: So I ask again: what problems did you encounter when you translate the months in the user TZ to UTC and use those to query?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's the boundary cases of daylight savings. I'll start using `pytz` but either way, this question is about using timezones in the SQLAlchemy query.

Comment: Yes, you said so before, but I don't know what those boundary cases *are*. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The boundary case is daylight savings. When displaying a calendar of events, you need to query for the events in local time or you lose events or gain some that don't belong. But again, that shouldn't matter. While it provides some context, the question is still about SQLAlchemy. (I'd like to know the answer even if the boundary case didn't exist.)

Comment: Since DST changes in the middle of a month and not at the start or end, I still don't see what the boundary case is you seem to have found. Does the code you posted break in some way?

Comment: @MartijnPieters ... I'm honestly not entirely sure. I just know I've run into this before and querying in local time solves all edge cases in a simple way. Should I remove the contextual background? Really, the SQLAlchemy query is *the only thing* I'm asking about here.